# Validar array dentro de un JSON en node.js

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, array

Necesito validar los campos dentro del array "Extras" realmente sean "Numero" y "Codigo_Pais" ademas necesito poder obtener los valor. AYUDA POR FAVOR!!

```
"Persona": [
    {
        "Nombre":"Maria", 
        "Apellido":"Vargaz",
        "Extras":[
            {
                "Numero":6666666,
                "Codigo_Pais":506
            }
        ],
        "Direccion":{
            "Pais":"Costa Rica"
        }   
    },
    {
        "Nombre":"Maria", 
        "Apellido":"Vargaz",
        "Extras":[
            {
                "Numero":6666666,
                "Codigo_Pais":506
            }
        ],
        "Direccion":{
            "Pais":"Costa Rica"
        }   
    }
    ]
```

Comment: la comunidad de SO.es te da la bienvenida, y para ayudarte necesita algun esfuerzo tuyo demostrado como ser los intentos que realizaste, edita tu pregunta y postea tu codigo porfavor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es difícil proponer algo sin saber como tiene que ser la validación o que quieres hacer en caso positivo o negativo. Te dejo un ejémplo de como acceder a los valores, pero cambiaría mucho dependiendo de que quieres hacer exactamente:

```js
var obj = {"Persona": [
    {
        "Nombre":"Maria", 
        "Apellido":"Vargaz",
        "Extras":[
            {
                "Numero":6666666,
                "Codigo_Pais":506
            }
        ],
        "Direccion":{
            "Pais":"Costa Rica"
        }   
    },
    {
        "Nombre":"Maria", 
        "Apellido":"Vargaz",
        "Extras":[
            {
                "Numero":6666666,
                "Codigo_Pais":506
            }
        ],
        "Direccion":{
            "Pais":"Costa Rica"
        }   
    }
    ]}
  
    obj.Persona.forEach(e => {
      e.Extras.forEach(v=>{
        console.log(v.Numero)
        console.log(v.Codigo_Pais)
      })
    });
```

Comment: Adapte ese ejemplo a mi código y funciono perfectamente!!

Muchisimas gracias!